# Creating M*N table and export and download excel file with java script in html page

Tags: javascript

Is there a way that the following script after creating the table (N * M) can finally receive and download Excel output from it. Of course, I mean without using Excel software DLLs.
The script for creating the table is as follows (Generates the script below the table but I do not know how to **convert it to Excel**.) :

```js
var rows = prompt("How many rows for your multiplication table?");
var cols = prompt("How many columns for your multiplication table?");
if (rows == "" || rows == null)
  rows = 10;
if (cols == "" || cols == null)
  cols = 10;
createTable(rows, cols);

function createTable(rows, cols) {
  var j = 1;
  var output = "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'>";
  for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    output = output + "<tr>";
    while (j <= cols) {
      output = output + "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
      j = j + 1;
    }
    output = output + "</tr>";
    j = 1;
  }
  output = output + "</table>";
  document.write(output);
}
```

Comment: You can explore [SheetJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx). It helps you convert html tables to a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. If possible please send me a sample code @Zohaib Ahmed

Comment: You can find example code on Sheetjs's site. https://sheetjs.com/demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be just encode the table and save as excel -

```js
var rows = prompt("How many rows for your multiplication table?");
var cols = prompt("How many columns for your multiplication table?");
if (rows == "" || rows == null)
  rows = 10;
if (cols == "" || cols == null)
  cols = 10;
createTable(rows, cols);

function createTable(rows, cols) {
  var j = 1;
  var output = "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'>";
  for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    output = output + "<tr>";
    while (j <= cols) {
      output = output + "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
      j = j + 1;
    }
    output = output + "</tr>";
    j = 1;
  }
  output = output + "</table>";
  document.write(output);
  const html = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].outerHTML;
  var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
  location.href = url;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f48ev5k/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using function `exportToExcel` below. It takes tableString string & downloads `export.xls` file with this table.

```
var rows = prompt("How many rows for your multiplication table?");
var cols = prompt("How many columns for your multiplication table?");
if (rows == "" || rows == null)
  rows = 10;
if (cols == "" || cols == null)
  cols = 10;

function createTable(rows, cols) {
    var j = 1;
    var output = "<table border='1' width='500' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='5'>";
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    output = output + "<tr>";
    while (j <= cols) {
      output = output + "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
      j = j + 1;
    }
    output = output + "</tr>";
    j = 1;
  }
  output = output + "</table>";
  return output;
}

/*
* Export table string as excel
*/
function exportToExcel(tableString){
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
        var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'; 
        var base64 = function(s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        };

        var format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };

        var ctx = {
            worksheet : 'Worksheet',
            table : tableString
        }


        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "export.xls";
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.click();
}

// create table as a string
const tableString = createTable();

// export table string to excel (be sure that popups are allowed in your browser)
exportToExcel(tableString)
```